# Is there a visualization method that we can identify the same transactions on time series data?

Tags: javascript, python, data-visualization, visualization

I'm looking for a method to make this kind of image:

[image]

(reference: https://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/2015-spoofing/)

Timeseries, and we can connect the same data (ex. transactions by the same person on e-commerce or trade transactions by the same investor).

Python or javascript code is highly appreciated, but other (GUI tool maybe?) is also sufficient.

Also, I want to know the name of this kind of graph.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try d3.js https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery 
It's simply easy to integrate.
And if you're using react try react-vis
https://uber.github.io/react-vis/

Comment: Thank you! I knew D3.js but I did not dig into it recently. I revisited the gallery and I found [this one](https://github.com/danielgtaylor/bibviz), which seems enough :)